# Git Default Editor Configuration

Tags: git

Working in Powershell, my primary goal is to revert a merge from a collaborator.

When I run `git revert -m 1 <SHA of merge>`
git returns:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... C:\Users\Hugh\emacs\bin\runemacs.exe: 
C:UsersHughemacsbinrunemacs.exe: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'C:\Users\Hugh\emacs\bin\runemacs.exe'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I restarted my computer and recloned the repo but got the same result.

After some googling, I decided to try changing my default editor, from emacs to nano and ran:

```
git config --list
```

which returned:

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
core.editor=nano.exe
user.email=hghklly@gmail.com
user.name=Hugh
core.editor=C:\Users\Hugh\emacs\bin\runemacs.exe
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:ucfnmyo/SDC_MuseumsProject.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

You can see that there are two entries for `core.editor`, `nano.exe` without a file path and the full file path for `runemacs.exe`.

I checked my local and global config files, neither specify emacs.

config contents at `C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig` :

```
[http]
    sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    sslBackend = openssl
[diff "astextplain"]
    textconv = astextplain
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
[credential]
    helper = manager
[core]
    editor = nano.exe
```

local config contents:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:ucfnmyo/SDC_MuseumsProject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

config contents at `C:ProgramData/Git/config` :

```
[core]
    symlinks = false
    autocrlf = true
    fscache = true
[color]
    diff = auto
    status = auto
    branch = auto
    interactive = true
[help]
    format = html
[rebase]
    autosquash = true
```

I also checked my windows defaults, for `.txt` files it is Notepad.

Any suggestions for (1) how to remove emacs as a default git editor, or (2) simply how to work around this issue for reverting a merge?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three places where Git can be configured:

1. System
2. Global
3. Local

Since you've already checked global and local, the emacs editor must be specified in the system configuration.

You can open this file for editing at `C:\ProgramData\Git\config` if you are running anything newer than Windows XP.  Typically you could use a git command like `git config --edit --system`, but since your editors are out of sync, that will not work.

**Update**

To list all config files: `git config --list --show-origin`

Then, manually go through them with an editor and delete the properties that are duplicates.

Comment: thanks, I checked ProgramData but didn't see emacs specified there either...  Updated my Q to clarify the directories of the files I'm checking.

Comment: What does `git config --list --system` give you?

Comment: used `git config --list --show-origin` it looks like there are config files in `local`,  `ProgramData`,  `ProgramFiles`, and `C:/Users/Username/.gitconfig` .  It was the last directory that had emacs listed. Delete the whole file? Delete the line? Replace the value?

Comment: `--system` gave `http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
core.editor=nano.exe`